# Bind custom object to TreeView in WPF

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, treeview

I have a object of a class defined below

```
class XYZ
{
    List<XYZ> child;
    String header;
}
```

I want to bind this object to a tree view. Initially XYZ root will be the topmost TreeViewItem. root will have the List child as the sub TreeViewItems. This will go on recursively until List of each XYZ object is not empty. Each TreeViewItem is either a node or a leaf (if List child is empty).

I am able to do this programmatically by adding TreeViewItem as a child to parent TreeViewItem.

The number of levels is not known.

I referred this answer [Bind Object to WPF TreeView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2877717/bind-object-to-wpf-treeview) but here it is mentioned for a three level hierachy.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You just need to define the Hierarchical Datatemplate for your viewmodel and that should take care of the multiple levels in your treeview.

Make sure the collection you are using implements INotificationPropertyChanged

The datatemplate will be in the lines of

```
<TreeView ItemsSource={Binding child}>
<TreeView.Resources>
<HierarchicalDataTemplate ItemsSource="{Binding child}" DataType="{x:Type vm:XYZ}">
<Grid>
<TextBlock Text="{Binding header}"/>
</Grid>
</HierarchicalDataTemplate>
</TreeView.Resources>
</TreeView>
```

Comment: Why downvote??? The OP asked how to build a dynamic treeview and I provided a Datatemplate for that. Ofcourse he did not provide any code I had to guess his implementation and provide a guide atleast for a solution!